# Use cycle only once

Tags: c#

I am making a trivia game which has diferent help options, but the user can only use it once.
I know that I need to have a bool variable to do so, but I don't know how to do it.

example of the 50/50 help.

```
 else if (key_pressed.Equals("1"))
            {
                char c;
                string erradas = "";

                for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    if (!levels[current_level][x][i].Equals(resp))
                    {
                        c = (char)(i + 64); 
                        erradas = erradas + c;
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        c = (char)(i + 64); 
                        respostas = respostas + c;
                    }
                }
                ajuda_used = true;
                respostas = respostas + HELP5050(erradas); 
                continue;
             }

 public static string HELP5050(string opcoes)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int r = rand.Next(0, 2);
        return (opcoes.ElementAt(r).ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? This will ensure that the inner scope will be accessed only once per class instance / application run if you have it in your main function.

```
bool bonusUsed = false;

if(!bonusUsed)
{
    // do your thing
    bonusUsed = true;
}
```

Fitting this to your situation, I guess that `key_pressed.Equals("1")` should invoke 50/50 help. So

```
bool fiftyFiftyUsed = false;

...

else if (key_pressed.Equals("1"))
{
     if(fiftyFiftyUsed)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You have already used this help.");
         continue;
     }

     char c;
     string erradas = "";

     for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
     {
         if (!levels[current_level][x][i].Equals(resp))
         {
             c = (char)(i + 64); 
             erradas = erradas + c;
         }
         else
         { 
             c = (char)(i + 64); 
             respostas = respostas + c;
         }
     }
     ajuda_used = true;
     respostas = respostas + HELP5050(erradas); 
     continue;
     fiftyFiftyUsed = true; // <-- and do not forget to set this
 }
```

Comment: Will this run the cycle only once? edit. I tried to implement this. But i can use this help again.

Comment: can I ask you another thing?

Comment: Now when I click "1" the help doesn't appear, but how do I make it to say like: "You already used this help. try another one"

Comment: the writeline doesn't appear, when I click "1" and press enter the program automatically advances to the next question, without giving me the "error"

Comment: You probably left `&& fiftyFiftyUsed` in this line `else if (key_pressed.Equals("1"))`

Comment: No sir. I did everything acording to the "book"(as you show) . But I think this is because of a previous bug, which basicly is when you press a diferent key of (A,B,C,D - answer possibilities or 1,2,3,4 - HELP possibilities) the program incresess another level and it gives me another question without picking the correct one.